# What daily checklist items are there for coldfusion, iis7, sql server administrators?

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, coldfusion

That is going to be part of a site app tool i am creating that has many different functions.

But my question today, is for sql, iis, coldfusion administrators, what kind of daily checklists, do you use or do. Can any of those be checked/done/verified via coldfusion/sql/wmi?

For example, in this include as part of my main app, I am checking the following:

1. Verify Datasource
2. Verify all sql jobs are completing
3. Verify All SQL Backups, and when last run
4. Verify that I have at least 15% hard drive space

But what else can i check or add to my tool to check for me? So I can have an automatic summary of things checked, and alerts via the web, what I need to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of these will apply.  What you need depends more on your application than a generic list could provide.  Possibilities include:

- Scheduled tasks completed successfully
- Nothing new in CF error logs
- new undeliverable mail
- list of 404 pages and request counts
- total pages served
- total bandwidth used
- peak bandwidth used
- avg page response times, aggregate and per-page
- max page response times, aggregate and per-page
- avg/max cpu load
- avg/max RAM allocation usage
- avg/max total RAM usage

Remember, your hosting and application will define what you need to look at.

For example, I worked on an application that sent thousands of emails a day to user-entered email accounts, so we ignored undeliverables.  You might only send a handful to corporate users, where undeliverables would be critical.

So, figure out what is critical to your solution, and watch that.

Comment: Fair enough, but what if any of these, can i get as a summary via a query or cfadministrator api?

Comment: Most of these can be gotten pretty easily.  There are 3rd party log analyzer tools for IIS logs, or you can write your own.  I don't know anything about the administrator API, but if the CF logs aren't available through it, you can read them yourself.  Depending on your SQL server variant, you can monitor what it is doing.  There are tools for looking at Windows performance.  I'd decide what you want, then figure out how to do it.  There's always a way.  The question comes down to whether it's worth the time to implement.

Comment: I will be creating coldfusion pages, that will try to access the data via reading txt files, wmi, or cfadmin api.

Answer (score 1):

for SQL Server, here is a partial list

- Any errors in the error log
- did any backups fail
- fragmentation of indexes
- did CHECKDB run correctly
- free space on drive (you can run xp_fixeddrives to get that info)
- any jobs that failed, what step did they fail on
- outdated statistics
- [buffer cache hit ratio and page life expectancy](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/use-sys-dm_os_performance_counters-to-ge)

See here for daily, weekly and monthly tasks  http://www.rodcolledge.com/rod_colledge/2009/02/suggested-dba-work-plan.html

Comment: That's all good examples, I am looking for items that i can run a quick sql query, and get a definite summary/indicator, that something needs to be looked at, or yes okay everything's fine.

I will show a preview of what i've got so far...

Answer (score 1):

These may not be daily items, they may be weekly or monthly, but you definitely want to manage the IIS logs to make sure they don't eat too much hard drive space on the server.

Also, if you're storing your SQL backups on the server you'll want to manage them and depending on your SQL recovery model and backup strategy you'll want to keep an eye on transaction log growth as well.